# RegexStorm.net: How to add \n in Replacement

Tags: regex, powershell, replace, end-of-line

I have this regex to match:

```
(\<div class=\"(?:right).*)(\<p)
```

This is the input string:

```
<div class='mid'>Nov 11, 2016</div>
<div class="right">xxx yyy zzz<p>11/11/16 - 13:41</p></div>
```

It matches OK. I want to insert `\n` into the replacement so that `<p>` is in another line, but couldn't find a way.
These all fail:

```
$1\n$2
$1\\n$2
$1`n$2
$1``n$2
"$1`n$2"
```

I know, in Powershell, quote with backtick can used for this regex. `` "xxx `n yyy" `` . But how to do that in RegexStorm page?

Had tried inserting

```
\\n
`n
``n
`\n
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you already know, in PowerShell you can use the escape sequence `` `n `` in an expandable string literal to insert a line break:

```
$inputString -replace '(\<div class=\"(?:right).*)(\<p)',"`$1`n`$2"
```

For the form on RegexStorm.net, simply put a literal linebreak (hit the ENTER key on your keyboard) between two replacement references, eg `$1<linebreak goes here>$2`:

```
$1
$2
```

Screenshot of linebreak in replacement:

[image]

This also works in PowerShell:

[image]